# Using async in non-async method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asynchronous, async-await

Lets say I only want one method to run in `async`.

So I have an `async` method like below:

```
public async Task Load(){
    Task task1 = GetAsync(1);
    Task task2 = GetAsync(2);
    Task task3 = GetAsync(3);
    var data1 = await task1; // <--Freezes here when called from GetSomethingElse()
    var data2 = await task2;
    var data3 = await task3;
    ..process data..
}
```

And then I'm trying to call that `async` method in another method as a task, and would like for it to wait until that particular piece of `async` code is done. The problem is it's not. When it reaches the first `await` in `Load()` it just doesn't finish loading. The debugger goes blank and gives no other error.

Is an `async` method able to be called from a non `async` method, like this?
There is a reason I do not need this particular task to be `async`, but the `Load()` function I do.

```
public void GetSomethingElse(){
    var task1 = Load().Wait();      
}
```

How is this possible?

---

I tried even changing the `Load()` method to use `var data = task1.Wait()`, etc. instead of `await`, still no difference, no matter which way I try.  If anyone can help it would be appreciated.

Comment: try: `var data1 = await Task.Run(() => GetAsync(1));`

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx

Comment: @JohnWoo I did try `var data1 = task1.Wait();` would doing it your way be any different?

Comment: I can see one difference: John's method guarantees that a worker thread is spun up.  Did you check out the article I linked?

Comment: @JohnWoo I used your suggestion in `GetSomethingElse()` instead and it works. If you would like to make an answer, I will accept. Thank you btw.

Comment: @ControlFreak @JohnWoo using a different thread with `Task.Run` is just a workaround to avoid the synchronization context. see my answer...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably have a deadlock on your hands. You're blocking a thread using `Wait()` on a task that needs that thread to complete because there's a `SynchronizationContext` being used in ASP.Net (also in GUI environments).

You should use `ConfigureAwait(false)` to tell the awaiter not to capture that context. It's enough to do that on the first `await` since the rest would have no `SynchronizationContext` to capture:

```
public async Task Load()
{
    Task task1 = GetAsync(1);
    Task task2 = GetAsync(2);
    Task task3 = GetAsync(3);
    var data1 = await task1.ConfigureAwait(false);
    var data2 = await task2;
    var data3 = await task3;
    //..process data.
}
```

However, it's recommended to always use `ConfigureAwait` unless **you want** to capture the `SynchronizationContext` so a better standard is this:

```
public async Task Load()
{
    Task task1 = GetAsync(1);
    Task task2 = GetAsync(2);
    Task task3 = GetAsync(3);
    var data1 = await task1.ConfigureAwait(false);
    var data2 = await task2.ConfigureAwait(false);
    var data3 = await task3.ConfigureAwait(false);
    //..process data.
}
```

In your case, where you want to continue after **all** the tasks completed you should use `Task.WhenAll` instead of `await`ing each task separately:

```
public async Task Load()
{
    await Task.WhenAll(GetAsync(1), GetAsync(2), GetAsync(3)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    // process data.
}
```

---

Note: doing *sync over async* is usually discouraged as it has no benefits (you're blocking a thread throughout the entire operation) and may cause deadlocks (like this one).

Comment: What if `GetAsync` returns a variable? And are you saying that I'll still run into deadlocks using this method?

Comment: @ControlFreak No. ConfigureAwait solves that. Task.WhenAll is just more comfortable in this case.

Comment: @ControlFreak I've updated the answer to make that more clear.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a classic deadlock scenario. See [this post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) for more details. When you have an `await` statement the current `SynchronizationContext` is stored before the `await` call and restored afterwards and the rest of the method posted to it. In GUI app there is only one thread associated with that context so the rest of the method is attemted to be executed on the GUI thread but it can't
because `Wait()` is a blocking call which blocks the GUI thread.

Try this instead:

```
public async Task Load(){
    Task task1 = GetAsync(1).ConfigureAwait(false);
    Task task2 = GetAsync(2).ConfigureAwait(false);
    Task task3 = GetAsync(3).ConfigureAwait(false);

    var data1 = await task1; // <--Freezes here when called from GetSomethingElse()
    var data2 = await task2;
    var data3 = await task3;
    ..process data..
}
```

If there are any awaits inside `GetAsync` you may have to add `.ConfigureAwait(false)` there as well.

Answer (score 1):

You would change your Load function as following:

```
public async Task Load(){
    await new TaskFactory().StartNew(() =>
    {
        Task task1 = GetAsync(1);
        Task task2 = GetAsync(2);
        Task task3 = GetAsync(3);
        var data1 = await task1; // <--Freezes here when called from GetSomethingElse()
        var data2 = await task2;
        var data3 = await task3;
        ..process data..
    });
}
```